# AddressOf operator not compiling on MacOS

Tags: vba, macos

The following code works fine for Windows when running under Office x32 and x64 but it does not compile in VBA x64 on MacOS:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestAddressOf()
    Debug.Print GetAddress(AddressOf GetAddress)
End Sub

Function GetAddress(ByVal addr As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    GetAddress = addr
End Function
```

I simply get an **Out of Memory** error. I've tried passing `AddressOf MethodName` directly to an API (declared using `Declare`) and I get the same result.

As soon as I remove the `AddressOf` operator all code compiles with no errors.

I am using MacOS 11.5.1 (20G80) with Excel x64 for Mac v16.16.27 (201012).

Can anyone test and confirm this behaviour on other versions of Mac/Excel?

Comment: For me it works fine: *Excel x64 for Mac v16.66.1 (22101101)*, *MacOS 11.3.1*

Comment: Thank you @GWD, I've upgraded to Office 365 version 16.69 (23010700) and now it works fine.